# Corrupt Word docx (OpenXML) fixed by Libreoffice - how to identify possible root cause?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, docx, libreoffice

I am trying to identify the root cause of a corrupted Microsoft Word docx, the file being the result of a PDF conversion using commercial software. When trying to open this doc in MS Word, I get an error message saying nothing specific, only that the file is corrupted and cannot be opened.

Now, the same file opens fine in Libreoffice. When saving the file as docx from within Libreoffice, I am also able open it in Word again. There are quite a few differences in the contents of the XML files in the unzipped docx file (checked with a diff tool) compared to the one created by Libreoffice. However, I am not sure which ones exactly would cause the file create by Libreoffice to be uncorrupted.

Also, if I unzip the docx and rezip it again, it also opens fine in Word afterwards. I checked the two files on the binary level using a Hexeditor and there were quite a few differences, but it is rather hard or even impossible to understand what these differences mean.

Has anyone has a similar situation and might be able to shed some light on this? I am not sure where to start. Tks.

Comment: This is off-topic in this forum. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic All conversions introduce anomalies. There is no one-to-one correspondence in features.The person with the most knowledge of xml problems with Word documents is Doug Robbins, to my awareness. I do not know that he participtates here., he does on the Microsoft Community Forums. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word

Comment: Thank you, Charles. In the meantime, we have managed to work around the problem by doing a roundtrip conversion using the Apache POI library (https://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by doing a roundtrip conversion using the Apache POI library (poi.apache.org)